# Searchkick aggregations for has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch

I have a Rails 5 app and I'm trying to do an aggregations search for a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association.

Here is the code that I have so far:

event.rb:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  searchkick text_start: [:title]

  has_and_belongs_to_many :services
  has_and_belongs_to_many :sectors

  def search_data
    atributes.merge(
      title: title,
      description: description,
      sector_name: sectors.map(&:name),
      service_name: services.map(&:name)
    )
  end

end
```

events_controller.rb:

```
def index
  query = params[:j].presence || "*"
  conditions = {}
  conditions[:sector] = params[:sector] if params[:sector].present?
  conditions[:service] = params[:service] if params[:service].present?
  conditions[:date] = params[:date] if params[:date].present?
  @events = Event.search query, where: conditions, aggs: [:sector, :service, :date], order: {created_at: {order: "desc"}}, page: params[:page], per_page: 10
end
```

When I call `Event.reindex` in the console I was expecting to to show that the sectors and services had been indexed but it doesn't work.

To be honest I'm getting quite lost and going round in circles so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm trying to do the same (using habtm associations as aggregations), but I'm completely lost.

Comment: Yeah I did. I've added the code that worked for me as an answer. Hope it helps you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the code that ended up working for me:

`event.rb:`

```
def index
    query = params[:j].presence || "*"
    conditions = {start_date: {"gte": "now/d"}}
    conditions[:sector_name] = params[:sector_name] if params[:sector_name].present?
    conditions[:service_name] = params[:service_name] if params[:service_name].present?
    conditions[:start_date] = params[:start_date] if params[:start_date].present?
    @events = Event.search query, where: conditions, aggs: [:sector_name, :service_name], order: {start_date: {order: "asc", unmapped_type: "long"}}, page: params[:page], per_page: 10
end
```

`events_controller.rb:`

```
def search_data
  {
    title: title,
    location: location,
    description: description,
    start_date: start_date,
    sector_name: sectors.map(&:name),
    service_name: services.map(&:name)
  }
end
```